# How to write T-SQL Recursive Query to return hierarchical data using common self-joining table to store tree data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

Every time I try to revisit recursive queries I feel like I am starting over. I am wanting to query data from a table that stores hierarchical data using a common method, having a table that self-joins.

First of all, there is this table that stores "Groups", i think of as being "folders" using a Windows Explorer analogy. The ID is the PK and there is an associated group Name.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BPAGroup](
    [id] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BPAGroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Second and lastly, there is a relationship table that associates a group with its parent group.  "GroupID" identifies "MemberID"'s group. For example, if you join up BPAGroupGroup.MemberID to [BPAGroup].ID, [BPAGroup].Name would contain the name of the group. if you join up BPAGroupGroup.GroupID to [BPAGroup].ID, [BPAGroup].Name would contain the name of the PARENT group.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BPAGroupGroup](
    [memberid] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [groupid] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BPAGroupGroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [memberid] ASC,
    [groupid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
-------------------------
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BPAGroupGroup]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BPAGroupGroup_BPAGroup_groupid] FOREIGN KEY([groupid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BPAGroup] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BPAGroupGroup] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BPAGroupGroup_BPAGroup_groupid]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BPAGroupGroup]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BPAGroupGroup_BPAGroup_memberid] FOREIGN KEY([memberid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[BPAGroup] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BPAGroupGroup] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BPAGroupGroup_BPAGroup_memberid]
GO
```

Here's some sample data in the form

```
Level1
   Level2
       Level3
```

and the SQL for the data

```
INSERT [dbo].[BPAGroup] ([id], [name]) VALUES (N'A', N'Level1')
INSERT [dbo].[BPAGroup] ([id], [name]) VALUES (N'B', N'Level2')
INSERT [dbo].[BPAGroup] ([id], [name]) VALUES (N'C', N'Level3')
INSERT [dbo].[BPAGroupGroup] ([memberid], [groupid]) VALUES (N'B', N'A')
INSERT [dbo].[BPAGroupGroup] ([memberid], [groupid]) VALUES (N'C', N'B')
```

How can I write a recursive T-SQL Server Query that returns all of the groups names, the recursion  "level number" and IDs for all of the groups. Of course, the root of the tree would have a NULL ParentID and ParentName?

For example, these fields would be in the result set.

Level, GroupID, GroupName, ParentId, ParentName

I realize that there are multiple ways  to store this type of data. I don't have flexibility to change the db design.

Ideally, the result should show all group names, even the root node, that doesn't have a parent.

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected results please? I suspect I know the answer, however, I'd have to make some guesses on your data.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, I'll make the GUID field a varchar and come up with all the SQL for the schema and data that you need.Working on it now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the latest data, this appears to get you the result you want:

```
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT 1 AS Level,
           id AS GroupID,
           [name] AS GroupName,
           CONVERT(nvarchar(10),NULL) AS ParentID, --This'll be uniqueidentifier in your real version
           CONVERT(nvarchar(255),NULL) AS ParentName
    FROM BPAGroup G
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM BPAGroupGroup e
                      WHERE e.memberid = G.id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Level + 1,
           G.id AS GroupID,
           G.[name] AS GroupName,
           r.GroupID AS ParentID,
           r.[GroupName] AS ParentName
    FROM BPAGroup G
         JOIN BPAGroupGroup GG ON G.id = GG.memberid
         JOIN rCTE r ON GG.groupid = r.GroupID)
SELECT *
FROM rCTE;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1b95ba562e06891b681ace329bb7f85)

It's important you understand how this works though. As you said in your post, you seem to need to revisit these each time. There's nothing wrong with needing to check the syntax for something (there's some things I fail miserably at remembering sometimes, especially the new `OPENJSON` stuff), but do you understand how this works? If not, which bit don't you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see my updated SQL to helpo you come quickly up with a working tables with sample data.

Comment: Looks like I guessed the meaning of `memberid` and `groupid` the wrong way round @ChadD. Will test in a bit, but this might get you there beforehand

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at it but I'm still mentally a long way off from  getting this.

Comment: @ChadD updated for you; I assume that's what you're after?

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that there was a Filldle for SQL. Strange that it seems to work there but not in SQL Server 2012, where I get this error: "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "ParentID" of recursive query "rCTE".". In my example , I changed the IDs from uniqueidenifier data type for varchar(10) just to make it easy. Even if it worked in SQL Server, I am starting to wonder if there'll be more type conversion issues...Do you have a local SQL database or have any idea what is causing the error in T-SQL?

Comment: Guessing you're getting that error in production, @ChadD ? Did you have a look at my comment in the T-SQL? `--This'll be uniqueidentifier in your real version`. One of the reasons why sample data using the same data types is important. I had to hard cast to a `nvarchar(10)`, but that's not your actual data type.

Comment: If not, @ChadD, can you create a fiddle that **replicates** the problem? Without being able to replicate it, it'll be impossible to fix; as this *does* work for the data you've provided.

Comment: I got it to work if I cast everything to their appropriate data types in both subqueries, ity even works with using the real uniqueidentifier datatype in the real db. I'm just not sure why it is necessary in T-SQL. Thank you for all your effort. I do understand it but I need to try imagining the stack processing of the query in order to fully comprehend it.

Comment: Yes @ChadD, the datatypes in a `UNION (ALL)` need to be the same in all queries. As i had `NULL` values, they had to be cast/converted to the correct datatype. Guessing the sample we had wasn't representative of the live data's data types, and hence why you got the error.

Comment: Understood! Thank you!